# Problema com Archive - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

tudo bem?

Estou utilizando um template premium chamado Beta Design. Mas no blog, a sidebar Archive não funciona. Ou seja, se eu clico para filtrar por mês/ano, ele não filtra...
Alguém por de ajudar?
Segue um print para ilustrar o problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado
Rafael

Comment: sendo premium talvez seja mais fácil pedir ajuda onde vc comprou. Normalmente eles tem foruns de suporte.

Comment: Já fiz isso... Mas não respondem... Obrigado...